# Regular Expressions assignment

Tags: python, regex

I am taking an online class for python. I've been at this for 2 weeks. I've written the following code to find numbers in a sample text document. The problem I'm having is when I move from line to line and run the regex, it finds the first set of numbers, then skips any remaining numbers on the line and moves to the next line where it matches only the first number on the line. My code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

try:
    fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
    fh = open(fname)
except:
    print 'Invalid Input'
    quit()

numlist = list()

for line in fh:
    nums = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
    if len(nums) < 1 : continue
    num = int(nums[0])
    numlist.append(num)

print (numlist)
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of the file? I'm confused what you mean when you say that it "finds the first set of numbers".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are explicitly telling it to skip all numbers but the first:

```
num = int(nums[0])
```

instead, use a list comprehension to coerce to `int` and append the entire list using `extend()`.

```
numlist.extend([int(x) for x in num])
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already noted, you're discarding all other numbers in the list and taking only the first element. You can use the `map` function to convert the numbers to `int` and then extend the list

```
for line in fh:
     nums = re.findall('[0-9]+',line)
     if len(nums) < 1 : continue
     nums = map(int, nums)
     numlist.extend(nums)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not looping on `nums`, but only appending the first item in the `nums` list.

To solve this, you should iterate on `nums` and append each item.